# How to crawl url again in google after url removal request? how much it take time?

Tags: google-analytics, seo, google-search, google-search-console, google-crawlers

I had remove website url `(http://www.example.com)` using the url removal request. but i want crawl it again. i had place request for indexing in `Web Master Fetch as Google` and also add in google `(https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/submit-url)`.

Its still not displaying in google search result. It's already take 2 - 3 Months. what i will do to crawl my url again.

Comment: You need to reinclude the website https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/59833?hl=en

Comment: I am unable to find `3. Select the Removed content tab`.

Comment: its to the right hand side.